# NSArray not finishing before TableView call?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsarray

In viewDidLoad I call

```
if (self.selectedObjectID) {
    CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];
    Location *locate = (Location*)[cdh.context existingObjectWithID:self.selectedObjectID error:nil];


    self.addressValue = [
        [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:locate.intersectionMain,
        locate.intersectionSide,
        locate.city,
        locate.zipCode,
        locate.county,
        locate.stateProvince,
        locate.country,
        locate.intersectionID,
        nil
    ];
}
```

By the time the table view calls:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

I get an issue with index beyond bounds on my addressValue variable. It claims there is only 1 item in the array. The funny thing is this exact code works great on the iPad but it breaks with the index beyond bounds on the iPhone. No matter what value from location is loaded first to the array I only ever have one. I don't understand. Is this an issue with running out of time. How can I fix this?

Comment: What value are you returning in `numberOfRowsInSection?` be aware that if any of the variables you pass to `initWithObjects` are nil, then that will act as the terminator and you will get fewer elements in your array. For example, if locate.city is nil then you will only have two elements in your array, intersection side and intersection main

Comment: Try looking at each object value in your `[[NSArray alloc] ..];` something may have returned nil, therefore the array will stop adding the rest of your objects. Happens to me a lot

Comment: I will check for nil on that. Any ideas why this issue would show on the iPhone but not iPad. My source data is the same.

Comment: I have no idea why different devices have different outcomes..Did all the objects check out ok, not nil?

Comment: I ended up writing a function the would pass in my values and check for nil. If it got nil it would return an empty string. Thanks for pointing the nil terminator out.

Comment: sure thing! did this resolved the problem of only having one object in your array, `self.addressValue`?

Comment: Yes. It works correctly now.

Comment: Awesome, so is there any issue to your question??

Comment: No, but the only answer to accept is not what really answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your model data from NSArray should always reflect what's used in the UITableViewDatasource. For that you should have the array with values loaded or an empty array, but not a nil one if it is used in the UITableViewDatasource methods.